azure devops couldnt produce aab
I make Ci Cd for azure devops and when it build flutter aab it throw this error:

Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file.

It's likely that this file was generated under D:\a\1\s\src\Flutter\Naadel\build, but the tool couldn't find it
i cheack the repo and i couldnt see the build folder i think when we push any changes the build folder doesnt upload
I am using flavor and this is my yaml file:
name: $(Rev:r)

trigger:
  - pipelines/production
  - pipelines/demo

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  PROJECT_DIRECTORY: "src/Flutter/Naadel"
  FLUTTER_VERSION: 3.19.2  # Assuming you don't need a custom version

stages:
  - stage: 'Build_Android'
    displayName: Build_Android_Version

    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: BuildingAndroid
        steps:
          - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '11'
              jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
              jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

          - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0  # Using aloisdeniel's extension
            displayName: 'Flutter installing'
            inputs:
              mode: 'auto'
              channel: 'stable'
              version: 'custom'
              customVersion: '$(FLUTTER_VERSION)'

         
          - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-build.FlutterBuild@0  # Using aloisdeniel's extension
            inputs:
              target: "aab"
              buildFlavor: 'googlePlay'
              projectDirectory: "$(PROJECT_DIRECTORY)"
              entryPoint: "lib/main.dart"
              iosCodesign: false
              buildNumber: "$(Build.BuildNumber)" 


Hi @AnwarSh, Have you got a chance to check my answer below and see if your project file was successfully pushed? Hope the information may point to the right direction to help resolve your issue. Thx and have a nice weekend.

From the current information, we are unable to know to why Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file without the actual error in the logs; however, as mentioned in your original post that tool couldn't find it I check the repo and I couldn't see the build folder I think when we push any changes the build folder doesn't upload, it seemed that failure was because the FlutterBuild task was unable to find the project file in $(PROJECT_DIRECTORY) which was defined as src/Flutter/Naadel.
For this, please check why the changes in your local repo were not pushed to your Azure Repo first and you may doublecheck the .gitignore file in your local repo if the path to that build folder was included in .gitignore. Then, push the commits again from local repo to one of your Azure Repos. Once you can observe the required project file is successfully pushed to cloud repo, you may test to run the pipeline with the correct path of $(PROJECT_DIRECTORY).
